# How to query a mysql database with Node.js to get specific users (fields) by name in url, not only by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js

I know how to query a SQLite Database with Node.js to bring back a specific key with the corresponding field information but I am unable to find the right syntax to do it in Mysql.

I want to put a specific station name in the url such as and result all its information from the database. example. http://localhost:5000/station/

The database result would be:

["station":"winton", "location":"123 Byers Lane", "property size":"3000"]

```
      <sqlite> needs to be put in <mysql>

      app.get('station/:stationid', req, res) => {
      const stationToLookup = req.params.stationid;
      db.all (
         'SELECT * FROM stores WHERE station = $station',
          {
          $station = stationToLookup
          },

           (err, rows) => {
               console.log(rows);
               if (rows.length > 0){
                   res.send (rows[0]);
               }else{
               res.send({});
            }
           });
          });
```

Comment: are you using any ORM?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with the term ORM....What does that mean? @SonuBamniya

Comment: ORM stands for Object Relation Model. and you can use sequalize, https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize

Answer (score 0):

You should install mysql driver first via npm. `npm install mysql`

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});
app.get('station/:stationid', req, res) => {
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM stores WHERE station ='" + req.params.stationid + "'", function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
    });
  });
}
```

**NOTE** how the double quotes and single quotes have been used in the code above. The query is inside **double quotes** and then the value of a field which we are going to find is between **single qoutes** embedded inside double qoutes just after the `=` sign.

Comment: @James.....I have mysql installed in node, however, I would like to use the app.get function so I can input a url......what url should I use?

Comment: Check the code above again I have updated it! I hope it helps you. Use `req.params.stationid` to access the stationid in the url.

Comment: @James......we both were thinking alike.....I just saw your solution after I posted one I worked on......both are the same......Thank you.....

Answer (score 0):

Here seems to be a solutioin.....@James @SonuBamniya

//(2)getting all stations names
app.get('/stationNames/:stationid',(req,res)=>{

const nameToLookup = req.params.stationid;

//console.log(nameToLookup);

db.query('SELECT * FROM stores WHERE station = ?', [nameToLookup],(err, rows, fields)=>{

if(!err)
        res.send(rows);
        else
        console.log(err);
      })
  });